# Hive TimeStamp Convertion from GreenPlum Code

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, greenplum

Please help me to convert below Greenplum code to Hive supported one.

GP:

```
date_trunc('second', now())::timestamp without time zone load_time
```

Expecting to convert similar operation and output in hive

Answer (score 0):

```
select timestamp(substr(current_timestamp,1,19)) as load_time
```

Result:

```
2022-02-08 13:18:27.0
```

`substr()` leaves only seconds, works as truncate.
and `timestampt()` - to convert from string to timestamp datatype.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @CascadiaJS thanks, explained